# How do you determine the amplitude and wavelength of a laser given its pulse position mod output diagram?

Tags: optics, laser

How do you determine the wavelength and amplitude of the laser that produces the PPM output in Figure 2 of this website:

https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/11180/111805E/Analysis-of-pulse-position-modulated-fiber-based-laser-systems-for/10.1117/12.2536113.full

[image]

As you can see in part a) above, there are two symbol frames.  How do I use the information provided in the symbol frames to determine properties of the laser that produced the symbol frames in the first place? There are two binary numbers in part a)  010 and 101 (2 and 5 in decimal).  How can they be used to go backwards and determine properties about the laser?

Comment: This isn't practical. Think about what's the $F$ term in your model? And what's the corresponding period $T=1/F$? For PPM to work, the pulse intervals need to be substantially shorter than $T$, like $T/8$ or shorter. And the individual pulses need to be a small fraction of that.

Comment: Now if you want to modulate a laser with PPM to encode a much lower frequency signal, that's certainly possible.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I just reworded my question.  Please let me know if this makes more sense to you. Basically I'm just wondering how to go backwards from a PPM diagram to determine properties of the laser.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The point of using a modulation scheme like PPM is that it makes the decoding not depend on the amplitude of the source. And if you don't know the wavelength of the laser, how did you choose the receiver to receive the signal with?

Comment: The goal of the PPM system is not to convey information about the laser. It's to use the laser to convey whatever other information you want to send, like the temperature of the satellite or a command from the ground station to take a photo or whatever. As an analogy, when you turn on your FM radio you don't do that to find out about the operating power and polarization of the radio transmitter, you do it to listen to news or music.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I see, that definitely makes sense.  Could you please point me to a tutorial where a simple "Hello World" message is transmitted? So the laser sends pulses and the receiver eventually gets "Hello World" received, or perhaps there is some noise and it receives "Hello Wor".